# Get Third Level Categories WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to get third Level WooCommerce categories. Here follows my source code:

```
$args = array(
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'show_option_none' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'parent' =>18,
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
);
$subcats = get_categories($args);
echo '<div class="wooc_sclist">';
foreach ($subcats as $sc) {
    $link = get_term_link($sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy);
    echo '<ul><a href="' . $link . '">' . $sc->name . '</a>';
$args2 = get_term(array(
            'hierarchical' => 0,
            'hide_empty' => false,
           // 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
        ));
        $subsubCats = get_categories($agrs2);
        foreach ($subsubCats as $subsubCats) {
            $SubLinks = get_term_link($subsubCats->slug, $subsubCats-
   >taxonomy);
            echo '<li>sub -<a href=' . $SubLinks . '>' . $subsubCats->name .'</a></li>';
        }
echo '</ul>';
}
echo '</div>';
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: and the question is? please edit the question, and make it very clear what is that you are asking

Comment: I was trying to get woo commerce third level categories means
-Cat One
 -- Cat Two
   --- Cat Three
trying to get third level categories

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it by my Self

```
      $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'parent' => $number = 16,
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    );
    $subcats = get_categories($args);
    echo '<div class="wooc_sclist">';
    foreach ($subcats as $sc) {
        $link = get_term_link($sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy);
        echo '<ul><a href="' . $link . '">' . $sc->name . '</a>'.$sc->term_id;
        $args2 = get_terms('product_cat',array(
            'child_of' => $sc->term_id,
            'hierarchical' => 1,
            'hide_empty' => 1,
        ));
        foreach ($args2 as $subsubCats) {
            $SubLinks = get_term_link($subsubCats->slug, $subsubCats->taxonomy);
            echo '<li>sub - <a href=' . $SubLinks . '>' . $subsubCats->name . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
    wp_reset_query();
```